# Grub bootloader not showing Arch Linux after installing Kali Linux and Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, arch-linux

I have recently set up a triple-boot configuration on my system with Arch Linux, Kali Linux, and Ubuntu. Initially, after installing Arch Linux, the Grub bootloader showed all the installed operating systems. However, after subsequently installing Kali Linux and Ubuntu, the Grub bootloader no longer displays Arch Linux as a boot option.

I have attempted to update the Grub configuration using the sudo update-grub command, but unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue. Is there a way to manually add an entry for Arch Linux in the Grub configuration to ensure that it appears in the boot menu alongside Kali Linux and Ubuntu?

My Arch Linux installation is on /dev/sda2, and the filesystem is Btrfs. Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It depends on which OS' Grub is in change. You may want to change it back to Arch's since that one was correctly detecting all of them.

Comment: thanks for response you are correct but the issue is currently ubuntu is in charge of grub and i am not able to boot arch anymore is there any way i can give charge of the grub to arch?

Comment: What I suggested is to be done in the firmware. UEFI ("BIOS") settings > Boot menu (or similar) then change it at "OS Selection" (or similar). It varies a lot so it isn't possible to give you an answer for your specific and unspecified system.

Comment: okh i understood but in the boot options i only have my hard drive as a option (where grub is installed from ubuntu) i have a lenovo t440 laptop 500 gigs of storage

Comment: i currently planning to format the arch partition and use sometihing else i am used to linux but first time installed arch it's quite frustrating

Comment: *i only have my hard drive as a option* Probably you did a Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" installation(s) where you should be using UEFI mode. In UEFI mode bootloaders co-exist and can be selected independently as I commented before. With the old method (no longer available in new hardware, BTW) the last installed OS is always in control of the boot process.

Comment: oh realy! i did'nt knew about that thing thanks for your response but actually i got it kali"s grub is able to recognise arch had mistakenly just done grub-update on kali instaead of installing it on sda and i thought that kali's grub is not recognising now it's working fine thanks ChanganAuto for your valuable response